# How do I use bat script as Chrome Native Messaging Host?

Tags: batch-file, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I know what the first response will be but my requirement is minimal and writing a script for that would be an overkill. All I want is to run a system command and send its output to the extension.
Here is what I have tried

```
@echo off
:strt
:: my code
goto strt
```

Doesn't work.
The above code give me an error message **Error when communicating with the native messaging host.**

Following example [Here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging)

Comment: Batch file doesn't interact with Chrome extensions. Go switch another language.

Comment: And also define "Doesn't work". Does it mean the code removes `System32`?

Comment: Doesn't work means: Getting this error message **Error when communicating with the native messaging host.**

Comment: May you please put it in your question?

Comment: And also what's your **exact** code? I don't believe posted your code give such error.

Comment: Code is ok. I have separately tested it out.No issues there.

Comment: Show us. If your code work then, what is this: `Error when communicating with the native messaging host.`???

Comment: I am guessing you are not familiar with chome extension api.

Comment: Yes. I am not familiar with it. But I guess your Chrome command is nothing, that's why it gives an error.

Comment: batch files can't read binary stdio pipes (chrome prepends each message with its uint32 length in 4 bytes) so the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm , for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: Using power shell to accomplish the task. Working fine

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `.bat` doesn't fulfil requirements for **chrome native messaging host** . My requirement from host was simple and using either python or c++ would be too much.I have opted for `powershell` to accomplish the task.

here is the `powershell` version

```
try {
$reader = New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader([System.Console]::OpenStandardInput())
$len = $reader.ReadInt32()
$buf = $reader.ReadBytes($len)
$msg = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($buf)

$nets = ConvertFrom-Csv (getmac /fo CSV /v)
..
..
..
# you get the point.
Response @{mac = $mac} }
```

Answering my own question and hoping it would help someone in future.

Comment: How did you determine that `.bat` files aren't allowed?

Comment: Definitely looks to be supported: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/host/

Comment: the link posted by @Slbox is currently broken (as many other related links)

Comment: @SantiagoRuiz here's another link: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/ - It's for the deprecated Chrome Apps, but it's the same concepts.

Comment: @Slbox, That batfile just launches Python.

Comment: The link I shared was only to demonstrate that `.bat` files are supported.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/2938c523066aa0b5903945999192afbe76167277/mv2-archive/api/nativeMessaging